# Импорт приложения Java FX на Android

Tags: java, android

Можно ли импортировать приложение, написанное на Java FX под андроид?Если да, то как?

Comment: Можно , но придется почти все (кроме логики, пожалуй) переписать с JavaFX API на Android API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Если Вы не использовали Java 8 API, тогда Вам даже не понадобится ничего переписывать. Вот [документация](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/). Если Вы предпочитаете [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbQqnTnqaKk).

Comment: спасибо, ознакомлюсь)